# Python 3.x : What is the simplest way to make "print" and "input" in one line?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new in python and I always encounter this problem when looping. What should I do to make the 'print' and 'input' in one line?

Please help me ^.^
This is my code

```
subjects = int(input("How many subjects do you have?"))
subject_grades = []
sum = 0
for e in range(0, subjects):
    print("Enter the grade of your subject number ", e+1, ": ", sep="")
    grade = int(input())
    subject_grades.append(grade)
    sum+=grade
average= sum/len(subject_grades)
print("The sum of your grades is", sum, "and the average is", average)
```

I expect the output of this code to be:

```
How many subjects do you have?3
Enter the grade of your subject number 1: 1
Enter the grade of your subject number 2: 2
Enter the grade of your subject number 3: 3
The sum of your grades is 6 and the average is 2.0
```

but the actual output is:

```
How many subjects do you have?3
Enter the grade of your subject number 1: 
1
Enter the grade of your subject number 2: 
2
Enter the grade of your subject number 3: 
3
The sum of your grades is 6 and the average is 2.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
grade = int(input("Enter the grade of your subject number " + str(e+1) + ": "))
```

instead of

```
print("Enter the grade of your subject number ", e+1, ": ", sep="")
grade = int(input())
```